# Traits of successful sites

Tags: website-design

I learned hard way creating websites.

Once it dawned on me that we should have social networking on our sites, then another day that a mobile version is required.

That we should register with Google Analytics and Google Webmaster Tools. Analysis with AWstats is also crucial for visitor stats. Successful sites are most likely on VPS or higher hosting.

Choosing right CMS is also important. Implied is good original content.

**Without making further discoveries .. I'd like to know from pro-webmasters the common traits of all successful sites.**

---

**UPDATE:** I'm not asking about the content or the quality of it. 
I want to know common features/functions of successful sites.

Comment: This question sounds too subjective - you can have very successful sites with none of the "traits" you mention. "Good original content" is usually mandatory, however, if you are providing a tool or service then even that is subjective (although I suppose that is then your "content")?

Comment: @w3d I've updated it.

Answer (score 3):

**Compelling and valuable content.** Some of the best sites *ever* still do not do social media, blogging, forums, etc. It not only about good content but compelling content and valuable content.

A user has to have a reason to come back over and over again. From there organic backlinks. Lot's of organic backlinks. Social media helps along with blogs, forums, etc., to get traffic, but if the **content** does not have value and is not compelling, then the site fails.

Answer (score 1):

Quality content on your website can provide users with the information they are looking for. Content also allows you to establish yourself as an expert in your field. The design of a good website should be simple, yet professional.professional. Rss feed,social-media, Blog can make it interactive. Other features like Seo, Analytic can be added as additional features.